# grouped bar charts with the line connecting the bars in c3.js

Tags: c3.js

I'm using c3.js to create a chart with grouped bars, where line connects each set of bars.
 I have used a combination of grouped bar charts and line graphs.

The expected graph to be:

[image: Expected]

But I'm getting the graph of form:

[image: Actual]

Is there any way to get the expected results.
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Can you please share code and data used, looks like it is not straight forward to do this using just c3 configs, you may have to override certain internal functions.